# Is exclusive use of angular cli for project setup scalable for an enterprise level project?

Tags: angular, frontend, enterprise

Mainly speaking, if you are a newbie to webpack, and you wanted to get right to angular programming without spending a lot of time doing set up, is use of angular CLI to create file structure and your basic config files (along with adding a few of your own additional dependencies) a bad idea?

I guess what I'm asking is, is angular cli a just a tool for angular 2 newbies to get right to coding in angular 2 and doing a little personal project or is it actually used by developers for project setup in an enterprise level environment?

Comment: 'is angular cli a just a tool for angular 2 newbies to get right to coding' - Short answer: yes

Comment: There's no harm using CLI for every project, as it will be compiled down to production anyway. But its a good way to learn and it gives you shortcut commands.

Comment: I think it should be stated that angular-cli's `ng serve` should NOT be used for production.  You should have a different setup to serve the files, once angular-cli has compiled them.

Answer (score 0):

The angular cli scales well for enterprise. It does make it easy as a newbies but with some simple practices like additional nesting of folders it makes for a clean easy solution even for large apps.

Additionally it is handy in enterprise because it keeps projects structured in a clean predictable manner. If an enterprise were to not use the cli they will likely use yeoman or something similar to unify structure. I also use it because it keeps my projects close to the best practices being suggested from google.

Just make sure to use the --prod flag for production builds.